# Unity: Hit to another car without affecting my car

Tags: unity-game-engine, standards, assets

I'm newbe in Unity.I'm using `Car` and `CarWaypointBased` prefabs in `Standard Assets` package,to create a car racing game.

I want to make a situation to hit the `CarWaypointBased` object without affecting Car object(
Like a car with super power!!).I mean ,it's as if my car was not hit (while makes another car to move).

Both have the default `Colliders` and `Rigidbody`.

Now collision causes both to move.
I hope it was clear.

**UPDATE**

I use `AddForce` in `OnTriggerEnter` of my car:

```
other.GetComponentInParent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(-transform.forward * 500f );
```

And i set weight of my car on 10000, another to 500.

Comment: Use colliders as triggers (toggle `IsTrigger` on your super car's collider). Then handle `OnTriggerEnter` or `OnCollisionEnter` events to push other game object

Comment: Thanks @alex-larionov .would you please give me more explain or example to push other game object ?

Comment: you'll need some math to find where and how much to push the objects. Then use `AddForce` on pushed objects

Comment: 10000/500=20, that is why you may set super_car's weight 20 and just car weight - 1. To work with little numbers is easier I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to set the weights in rigidbody components. Set weight about a million to super_car and 1 or less to just a car. It will fly away after touching. The less the difference between weights is the less the lighter car will fly away. Just experiment with weights